# Error while creating new entry in CDS View

Tags: odata, sapui5, hana, cds

I have created a service, below is the structure:

[image: Service]

I am fetching data successfully from that service.  Then displaying as a Smart table, as indicated below:

```
<smartTable:SmartTable id="detailRecordsSmartTable" entitySet="ZI_BSLiquidityGroups" smartFilterId="" tableType="Table" 
            useExportToExcel="true" beforeExport="onBeforeExport" useVariantManagement="true" 
            useTablePersonalisation="true" 
            header="" 
            showRowCount="true" 
            persistencyKey="DetailRecordsSmartTable_persistency" 
            enableAutoBinding="true" 
            class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding"       
            customData:useSmartField="true"          
            editTogglable="true" 
            editable="false"
            initiallyVisibleFields="Bukrs,Azdat,Ktonr,Belnr,Kukey,Esnum,Vgman,Texts,Lqpos,Texts,Kwbtr"
            beforeRebindTable=".onBeforeRebind">
```

Table has an additional button, to create new entries.  Since the smart table control it has enabled the auto binding, I have created a popup to enter the data, and once user hits save, below code gets triggered for the Create:

```
onSaveDialog : function () {
        var oModel = this.getModel(),
            data = {};

        data.Bukrs = this.getView().getModel("InputData").getProperty("/Bukrs");
        data.Kotnr = this.getView().getModel("InputData").getProperty("/Kotnr");
        data.Azdat = this.getView().getModel("InputData").getProperty("/Azdat");
        //data.Belnr = "111";
        //data.Kukey = "222";
        //data.Esnum = "333";
        data.Kwaer = this.getView().getModel("InputData").getProperty("/Kwaer");
        data.Kwbtr = this.getView().getModel("InputData").getProperty("/Kwbtr");
        data.Texts = this.getView().getModel("InputData").getProperty("/Texts");
        data.Lqpos = this.getView().getModel("InputData").getProperty("/Lqpos");
        data.Zregcl = this.getView().getModel("InputData").getProperty("/Zregcl");
        data.Zregfe = this.getView().getModel("InputData").getProperty("/Zregfe");
        data.Zregus = this.getView().getModel("InputData").getProperty("/Zregus");
        
        // Create a new entry through the table's list binding
        //oModel.setHeaders({"content-type" : "application/json;charset=utf-8"})
        oModel.setHeaders({
            "content-type" : "application/json;type=entry;charset=utf-8"})
        oModel.create( 
                "/ZI_BSLiquidityGroups", data
                , null, {
                success : function(oData, response) {
                    console.log("Create successfull");
            },
                error : function(oError) {
                    console.log(oError.responseText)
                    var msg = oError.responseText.split('message')[3];
                    MessageToast.show(msg);
            }
        });
        
        //oModel.submitChanges();
        this.byId("AddDialog").close();
        this.getView().byId("detailRecordsSmartTable").rebindTable(true);

        // Trigger event so Master View gets updated with latest changes
        var oEventBus = this.getOwnerComponent().getEventBus();
        oEventBus.publish("DetailTable", "Updated", this);  

        var msg = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle("detail.newRecordSaved");
        MessageToast.show(msg); 
    },
```

But no matter what I try, I always get the same response:

> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">`005056A509B11EE3AEB5819C07C69E2F`The server is refusing to process the request because
> the entity has an unsupported format

Does anyone have any idea on what I am doing wrong here? I just can't find it

Regards,
Martin

Comment: You may create a new entry when "add" button was pressed and bind your popup to the created context. Then in case of two way binding all the values would be passed to the model after user inputs something in the form fields. Then on save you will send the request to the backend without manual data retrievement. Anyway, there's nothing special about CDS in the code ot the question itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself.  Issue was a wrong parameter being passed to the create method.  The null shouldn't be there